# BEGIN..END not working in Nested IF..ELSE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am confused with the BEGIN.. END in the nested IF..ELSE condition.
For example, when I am trying to execute below mentioned query. It is 
returning an error -- **"Incorrect syntax near ElSE.."**

```
IF ( ISNULL(@tin,'')=''AND ISNULL(@prpr_ntwrk,'')<>'' )
BEGIN
    IF (ISNULL(@prpr_ntwrk,'')='P')
    BEGIN
            -- CODE     
    END                         
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
            -- CODE
    END

END
```

please suggest.

Comment: Isn't there a missing "THEN" ? (I don't know about Sybase-ase, but this looks pretty Pascalish, doesn't it ?)

Comment: I guess you are missing 2 `END`s. One for Inner `IF` and other for Outer `BEGIN`

Comment: can you post the complete query?

Comment: It should work, can you put full code?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my recommendations :

1.-Give more whitespaces in this part of your code so it can be legible and avoid problems.

```
IF ( ISNULL(@tin,'')=''AND ISNULL(@prpr_ntwrk,'')<>'' )
```

2.- Insert a new line after the last END

3.- Run everything on terminal with isql because interactive SQL can be buggy sometimes

4.-Post the code between the if and end please.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The code below executes on ASE 15.7.0

```
DECLARE @tin varchar, @prpr_ntwrk varchar

IF ( ISNULL(@tin,'')=''AND ISNULL(@prpr_ntwrk,'')<>'' )
BEGIN
    IF (ISNULL(@prpr_ntwrk,'')='P')
    BEGIN
        SELECT "P"
    END                         
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT "Not P"
    END
END
```

Note that ASE gets confused with the empty stubs "-- Code" in the original example.

Your first IF statement may not do what you want, but I am sticking to the question asked.